# Measuring what fraction of an image is covered by filaments

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to measure what fraction of an image is covered by filaments. 
I have tried several combinations of image processing functions without any luck. Any help?

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvh7c.jpg"];
```

[image]

Comment: this can be a start: `MorphologicalBinarize[GaussianFilter[img, 0.2], 0.42] // ColorNegate //MaxFilter[#, 1] &`

Comment: Thanks Ali, MaxFilter is great, but I need something sharper

Comment: `MorphologicalBinarize[BrightnessEqualize[img],0.43] // Opening[#, 2] & // DeleteSmallComponents[#, 100] &`

Answer (score 5):

Almost

```
HighlightImage[img,bin = MorphologicalBinarize[
   TopHatTransform[GaussianFilter[img, 10], 10], {.01, .02}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Fraction about those filaments

```
N[Total[ImageData[bin], 2]/Times @@ ImageDimensions[bin]]
```

> `0.278293`

Comment: Impressive, thanks a lot

Comment: Good answer. You could use `Mean@N@Flatten@ImageData@bin`, then you wouldn't have to divide by the number of pixels

Comment: @nikie Thanks,that is a good tech..

Answer (score 0):

**A HeadStart**

by no means it is a complete answer. But one can surely play around with it a bit

```
img2 = MorphologicalBinarize[GaussianFilter[BrightnessEqualize[img], 2], 0.44] //
Opening[#, 2] & // DeleteSmallComponents[#, 200] &

(* for cropped image i took *)
Length@PixelValuePositions[img2, 1]/(Times@@ImageDimensions[img])
(* ~ 0.20 *)
```

[image]

Comment: I found a little better result using PeronaMaikFilter, LocalAdaptiveBinarize, and DeleteSmallComponents functions

Comment: @JBogoya Great. Good that worked out for you

Comment: @JBogoya You can post your own solution as an answer, it is encouraged here.

Comment: DeleteSmallComponents[
  DeleteSmallComponents[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[PeronaMalikFilter[fig, 20], 250], 400] // 
   ColorNegate, 150] // ColorNegate